# Is there a way to read Tor bundle's session cookies?

Tags: cookies

Both local storage and the built in cookie viewer don't show anything. Reading `document.cookie` from the console only shows some of them (missing cookies with `HttpOnly` set). Is there a way to read all of current site's cookies in Tor?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that this is a feature/annoyance not just of Tor Browser but of Firefox in general when one is using private tabs. I frequently find in Firefox that I want to clear the cookies from a particular tab but when I try to look at what cookies there are, none show up. The only solution I have found in Firefox generally, is to close the browser and re-open it. In Tor Browser, I have found that using the Tor button to request a new circuit for the particular site will also solve the problem and clear the session cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the input - my problem was reading them tho. Wanted to grab the session cookie to test some scripts against .onion sites (or something like that, don't remember the specifics anymore).

Comment: This won't help you (!) but I just found a relevant bug report for Firefox, although the developers say that it is not a bug but a deliberate strategy: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=823941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little cumbersome but technically works:

In the developer tab when you select a request you can view the cookies which were sent with it (including HttpOnly cookies).

[image: developer tools]