# How to set Tor Browser to save temporary internet files?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

How do I configure Tor Browser so that is saves temporary internet files? I am using it on a website that generates audio files that normally you can locate in the temp cache folder in Firefox for example, but I have not found a way to do this in Tor?

Comment: Preferences -> Privacy -> Untick the private browsing? This will potentially break Tor Browser's protections in unanticipated ways and is a bad idea if you require anonymity.

Comment: OK and after I did that, which folder on the harddrive do the temp internet files end up in?

Comment: I've no idea :) it's not supported or even a good way to fetch media from websites.

Comment: You probably want to have a look under `Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default`

Answer (score 1):

First you must turn off Firefox's (i.e., Tor Browser's) private browsing mode. Private browsing mode renders [session cookies inaccessible](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9014/is-there-a-way-to-read-tor-bundles-session-cookies#comment14959_9014) and does not save temporary files. Go to preferences, choose the Privacy tab, and uncheck "Always use private browsing mode". Understand that you have now broken several of the features that the good folk at the Tor project have arranged to protect your anonymity!

Next, use Tor Browser in the way that you are used to with unbundled Firefox. Then search in the cache section of the `MAIN-TBB-FOLDER/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default` folder. The cache on Linux is the subfolder of profile.default called `cache2`. Within that folder, you will find numerous temporary files with long, temporary file names like `F4F839C323EEEDE457AA9C383A2B14BED29545DC` .

Before closing TBB, I copied all the cache files into another directory. Within that other directory, I used the Unix `file` command to discover whether the files were videos, jpeg images, etc. Next, I changed the extensions on each file to reflect its format so that I could open them in Windows if I wanted to.

Finally, I completely reinstalled the Tor Browser Bundle. Why? Because I was unsure whether the browser would be restored to its proper state simply by rechecking the "Always use private browsing mode".